# Cant connect to localhost mysql when firewall script is running

Tags: linux, mysql, debian, iptables

I have the following problem:
I cant get etherpad running, when my firewall rules are active.

My firewall: http://pastebin.com/82APzKhi

telnet localhost 3306 gives connection timeout

ps aux | grep mysql:

```
root     15212  0.0  0.0   4112   712 ?        S    13:54   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysql    15526  0.7  0.9 426056 75392 ?        Sl   13:54   0:27 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
root     15527  0.0  0.0   5512   720 ?        S    13:54   0:00 logger -t mysqld -p daemon.error
```

netstat -tan|grep 3306:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

When i turn my firewall off everything works.

mysql IS working as I use it already on my website and for other applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to connect to mysql locally because you have the rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.0/8    -j DROP
```

This rule will prevent any TCP/IP traffic destined to locahost (IP: 127.0.0.1). The other rules that allow loopback traffic can be found after this drop rule:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

So, they will be useless.

Comment: thx fixed :D I looked so long for that but couldnt find it thx again